# Why is it possible to write HTML inside Scalatra?

Tags: scala, scalatra

Take the following example :

```
package com.example.app

import org.scalatra._
import scalate.ScalateSupport

class MyServlet extends ScalatraServlet with ScalateSupport {

  get("/") {
    <html>
      <body>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        Say <a href="hello-scalate">hello to Scalate</a>.
      </body>
    </html>
  }
}
```

Is this a DSL? i am wondering about the mechanism of how this work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scala [natively supports xml](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/131) syntax and, by extension, xhtml. So no DSL, just a language feature.

Answer (score 4):

Scala has [support of XML literals](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/working-with-scalas-xml-support) on language level.

> Scala's XML literal syntax is actually sugar for a series of Elem and
>   Text instantiations